# Issuing multiple tokens for the same application

Tags: autodesk-forge

Would it be correct to issue multiple tokens for the same application to different users at the same time, or would it be better to use the same token for all users of the app. I'm just loading models from a bucket, but I want to be the one holding them.

Thanks.

Comment: for 2 legged it does not matter - 3 legged, you do not have the choice, it is one for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about 2-legged it doesn't matter as Cyrille mentioned, however I would recommend you issue multiple tokens for each request as needed. This will prevent you from implementing some extra logic to check if the token is still valid or not. I would also recommend you take a look at those articles and implement the proxy approach on your server:

[Securing your Forge Viewer token behind a proxy](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/securing-your-forge-viewer-token-behind-proxy)

[Securing your Forge Viewer token behind a proxy (.NET)](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/securing-your-forge-viewer-token-behind-proxy-net)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Philippe! Will definitely check out those links.